# Google Image Serving URL resize getting error

Tags: image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to resize my google serving url image with size 0px and crop.

My link as below getting error:

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AB-uiNFQXbUfnIZ6NXNJg-XNjN_smoMbY4SwkqAdPEQKxshtkWp0hx0IR2bi87Hkd_5a3KgbHDj5fMPw6LXuGzZJxPHdJ5aLAVWFWDw=s0-c

But if remove the resize and crop as below, the image display successful.
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AB-uiNFQXbUfnIZ6NXNJg-XNjN_smoMbY4SwkqAdPEQKxshtkWp0hx0IR2bi87Hkd_5a3KgbHDj5fMPw6LXuGzZJxPHdJ5aLAVWFWDw

What's wrong with my link? If I change to to other size like s100 the image is worked also. Can anyone explain to me? Thanks.

Note: the problem is not seen only for the 0 size image (with or without cropping), but also for other sizes, for example 600:

http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/AB-uiNFQXbUfnIZ6NXNJg-XNjN_smoMbY4SwkqAdPEQKxshtkWp0hx0IR2bi87Hkd_5a3KgbHDj5fMPw6LXuGzZJxPHdJ5aLAVWFWDw=s600

**Updated:**

Link below with s0 is no error.
http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4_q9hd8oKxXjW7QDM5faAE3iRsJcGdOF6l_XSCUQAD4Plzs0aipcULBMwncFmBAv7rTkUSjEzpzeX1tsAM1gU7d1SqLkMfTrhSjP8F8C=s0-c

Comment: I edited your post to mark the 0 size issue a red-herring and will delete my initial answer. You'll need to show all the code related to creating and serving those URLs to get help.

Comment: Are you by any chance using the Blobstore with the (now deprecated) Files API?

Comment: I don't have use Blobstore, i am refer from url here  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/images

Comment: any chance this image was originally a multi-layer TIFF when it was uploaded?  we've experienced problems with those in the past.  (also, to be specific your image only works between =s1 and =s512)

Comment: I'd contact google support: something may have changed (512 is a rather suspect value) and the doc might not be up2date. Might also be an actual issue on their side.

Comment: So means s1 is minimum value and s512 is the maximum value currently?

Comment: @NickFranceschina, but http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4_q9hd8oKxXjW7QDM5faAE3iRsJcGdOF6l_XSCUQAD4Plzs0aipcULBMwncFmBAv7rTkUSjEzpzeX1tsAM1gU7d1SqLkMfTrhSjP8F8C=s0 is s0 whith no error.

Comment: @HowardHee yes while most images will work as expected, I'm saying that we have had some image formats uploaded from users that google has trouble transforming (some multi-layered TIFFs, images with CMYK color pallette, images with a large amount of metadata in them).  It is definitely strange that it transforms between 1 and 512 yet errors outside of that.  Perhaps try loading it into their image library and transforming to see if you get any specific error messages?  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/

Comment: @NickFranceschina, i try upload same image again, is working fine. http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-DMKbv5jTvsMzV3Lt8KmmjbRb70d7nBo0YGWaz-DexFtM9z8JeEvzD4A57Kl68mBDycWQPOc37J104EoAtcAIIu_aQrWg2f9lvt1bPc=s0-c so means google changed something on their server side?

Comment: @howardhee not likely... the one you downloaded was generated by Google and so it didn't have whatever anomaly the original did

Comment: @NickFranceschina I am not download from the old Google link, I am upload new image from my pc to cloud storage again. The link I given to you is new google link auto generated by Google.

Comment: ah... well then I'm stumped! 